# Hudson Locks and Latches jenkins plugin build failed

Tags: maven, jenkins, hudson-plugins

I'm trying to build this jenkins plugin 
git: https://github.com/jenkinsci/locks-and-latches-plugin

`mvn install`

gives following error

> ERROR] Failed to execute goal
>   org.jvnet.hudson.tools:maven-hpi-plugin:1.54:apt-compile
>   (default-apt-compile) on project locks-and-latches: Execution
>   default-apt-compile of goal
>   org.jvnet.hudson.tools:maven-hpi-plugin:1.54:apt-compile failed: A
>   required class was missing while executing
>   org.jvnet.hudson.tools:maven-hpi-plugin:1.54:apt-compile:
>   com/sun/mirror/apt/AnnotationProcessorFactory

[ERROR] -----------------------------------------------------

any advice?

Comment: The plugin is eight years old ?

Comment: @khmarbaise yep, trying to make it work. any suggestions?